# Merge multiple parquet files to single parquet file in AWS S3 using AWS Glue ETL python spark (pyspark)

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet, aws-glue

I have AWS Glue ETL Job running every 15 mins that generates 1 parquet file in S3 each time.

I need to create another job to run end of each hour to merge all the 4 parquet file in S3 to 1 single parquet file using the AWS Glue ETL pyspark code.

Any one have tried it? suggestions and best practies?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

well.. an easy option would be to convert it into a spark dataframe

1) read the parquet into a dynamic frame (or better yet, just read it as  spark dataframe)
2) sourcedf.toDF().repartition(1)

Comment: Yup, did the same! will post the answer here